# javascript and fusion tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a javascript function which should filter a specific row from a shape file that is already uploaded in fusion tables using `shpescape.com`.I have used `layer.setquery()` method with filtering condition.But this query shows entire data from my table rather than filtering only the rows i have mentiooned in the query.since, I am new to google map.please suggest me the code for doing this.

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(2053430,{query:'select  boundary from 2053430 where layer=BOU'});

  layer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Map API Reference describes how to do this correctly:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#FusionTablesQueries

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(
    {query: {
     select:  'boundary',
     from: 2053430,
     where: "layer='BOU'"
          }
    });
```